# Is it possible to force traefik to response using http 1.1?

Tags: http, configuration, traefik

I have an application which perform http queries with the http 1.0 header, and expect answers to be in http 1.1.

Obviously, traefik is respectful of world wide web conventions and reply 1.0 to 1.0 queries, and 1.1 to 1.1 queries. But is it possible to modify that behaviour through configuration to have that application always reply using http 1.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to override HTTP version in Traefik. Sorry ;)